# Manipulating globals for multi-site?

Tags: multi-site, globals

I'm working on one Craft project with two sites (which have one shared page that is translated and possibly more in the future.) Is there a way to make the global header & footer for Site 2 redirect back to Site 1 pages instead of having to enable all of the Site 1 pages for Site 2 or hard code the links in?

English page - [www.mysite.com/](http://www.mysite.com/)
French page - [www.mysite.com/fr](http://www.mysite.com/fr)

Essentially I do not want any of the French header and footer links to go to, for example,  [www.mysite.com/fr/about-us](http://www.mysite.com/fr/about-us), just to [www.mysite.com/about-us](http://www.mysite.com/about-us).

When I'm changing one of the link entry destinations in the global, it looks like it will let me choose between the English and French, but when I save it it just shows a disabled entry.